# In which scenario do i need to provide spring class name as bean id value?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I need to configure xml file for DAO. So in my xml file, I have declared two entityManager Factory and I want to set one of them as **default persistence unit**. I have declared that part as below in my  dao.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="pumps-jpa"/>
</bean>
```

But, it didn't not work for me, it was not taking default persistence unit. I was getting error like this

> No unique bean of type is defined: expected single bean but found 2:

After lot of searching, I found one code snippet in which they have mentioned  bean id as spring class name i.e. **org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor**, as shown below

```
<bean id="org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
     property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="pumps-jpa"/>
</bean>
```

So, after mentioning this bean id, it is taking default persistence unit name. I want to know, why do I need to mention spring class (**org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor**) as bean id? Is it a kind of hack or something?

Whole dao.xml is declared below

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:${catalina.base}/conf/pumps-dbconfig.properties"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>${jdbc.driver}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>${jdbc.user}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>10</value></property>
    <property name="minPoolSize"><value>10</value></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>${jdbc.maxConnections}</value></property>
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections"><value>600</value></property>
    <!-- <property name="timeout"><value>0</value></property> -->   <!-- 0 means: no timeout -->
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod"><value>60</value></property>
    <property name="acquireIncrement"><value>5</value></property>
    <property name="maxStatements"><value>0</value></property>  <!-- 0 means: statement caching is turned off.  -->
    <property name="numHelperThreads"><value>3</value></property>  <!-- 3 is default -->         
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout"><value>0</value></property>
    <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout"><value>true</value></property>
</bean>

<!--
    Configuration for Hibernate/JPA
-->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pumps-jpa" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" /> 
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- DEFAULT PERSISTENCE UNIT DECLARATION -->  

 <bean id="org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="pumps-jpa"/>   
</bean>

<bean id="r-dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>${r-jdbc.driver}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>${r-jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>${r-jdbc.user}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${r-jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>10</value></property>
    <property name="minPoolSize"><value>10</value></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>${r-jdbc.maxConnections}</value></property>
    <!-- <property name="timeout"><value>0</value></property> -->   <!-- 0 means: no timeout -->
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections"><value>600</value></property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod"><value>60</value></property>
    <property name="acquireIncrement"><value>5</value></property>
    <property name="maxStatements"><value>0</value></property>  <!-- 0 means: statement caching is turned off.  -->
    <property name="numHelperThreads"><value>3</value></property>  <!-- 3 is default -->    
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts"><value>3</value></property>      
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout"><value>true</value></property>
</bean>

<!--
    Configuration for Hibernate/JPA
-->
 <bean id="r-entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pumps-jpa" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="r-dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" /> 
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="BaseDataConnection" class="com.myntra.commons.dao.impl.BaseDataConnection">
        <property name="roEntityManagerFactory" ref="r-entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: post the whole configuration xml

Answer (score 0):

I think your original problem was not what you meant! **By configuration you can refer to one of your Entity Manager's existing Persistence Unit implementations as 'the default persistence unit'!** You can do this in your XML config! persistence.xml in JPA is your persistence config your beans (configuration) xml is an other option to point to some of the defined persistence units.  Please post your whole config xml ...

For the rest of your problem with the Bean ID:
There is already a Bean in your container initialised with the same name.
The Container is using the Bean Id as a unique Id of your identifiable code fragment! If you use another name then your container will initialise another bean instance of the same class and give it the other name. However as I pointed out above this is not related to your problem! (Even if you can bypass your existing bean implementations and redefine your config if you do not have other options!)

Comment: Which bean has the same name in my container? I didn't get you completely :(

Comment: You do. :) The Id is unique. In case you want to use the same name / class to initialise a new bean you need to give it a new id ...